# Hölder's inequality with $p=1,q=\infty$ and SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, holder-inequality

I have an expression of an expectation of stochastic processes at time $T$,  $$\mathbb{E}[X_TM_T]$$
$M_T$ is a martingale such that $\mathbb{E}[M_T] = \mathbb{E}[M_0] = M_0 = 1 $. I am tempted to apply Hölder's inequality to write
$$\mathbb{E}[X_TM_T]\le \mathbb{E}[|X_T|]E[|M_T|^\infty]^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$$

My question is: is it possible to evaluate $E[|M_T|^\infty]^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$? As far as I know this is the infinity norm, which is usually defined as the max value of the elements, but I rarely see it with this expected value notation. What I hope is that we can use the martingale property of $M_t$ but after thinking more it seems maybe the martingale property doesn't matter for norms besides the 1-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remark, your Holder's inequality should be
$$\mathbb{E}[X_TM_T]\le \mathbb{E}[|X_T|]E[|M_T|^\infty]^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$$
($\mathbb{E}[|X_T|]$, not $\mathbb{E}[X_T]$)

About your question, it's all about the convention. What is the definition of $E[|M_T|^\infty]^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$? According to the [Hölder's inequality convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Conventions), this is the supremum of $M_T$. Hence, by definition
$$E[|M_T|^\infty]^{\frac{1}{\infty}}  := \sup |M_T|$$

Besides, without Holder's inequality, we have
$$E(X_TM_T) \le E(|X_T| \sup |M_T|) = E(|X_T|)\sup |M_T| $$

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a great answer. What I am seeing in my text book and now on wikipedia as well, is that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $||x||_\infty \le ||x||_1$. I'm not sure if we can apply it here? If so then we could continue the inequality like this: $E[|X_T|]\sup|M_T| \le E[|X_T|]E[|M_T|]$, but this can't be right, since $\sup|M_T|$ must be greater than the expected value. I'm wondering how I interpret this equivalence statement then: $||x||_\infty \le ||x||_1$?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind It depends on the context. I think what you see in the text book is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm  and then $$ |x|_{\infty} = \max \{|x|_i\} < \sum_i |x_i| = ||x||_1 $$ But in this problem, we use the Lp-norm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces and so
$$||M_T||_1 := E[|M_T|] \le  E[\sup|M_T|  \times 1 ] =  \sup|M_T| \times E[1] =   \sup|M_T| :=  ||M_T||_{\infty} $$

Answer (score 1):

If you use Holder's with $p=1,q=\infty$  you are assuming that $X_T \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$ and $M_T \in \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{P})$. Then you get that $\mathbb{E}[X_TM_T]< \infty$ and
$$|\mathbb{E}[X_TM_T]|\leq\mathbb{E}[|X_TM_T|]=\int|xm|d\mathbb{P}\leq\underbrace{\bigg(\int|x|d\mathbb{P}\bigg)}_{\|X_T\|_1=\mathbb{E}[|X_T|]}\|M_T\|_{\infty}=\mathbb{E}[|X_T|]C, \ \ \ C > 0$$
Mind the infinity seminorm is not really $(\int|m|^\infty\mathbb{P})^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$, if you say $M_T \in \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{P})$ it just means that $M_T$ is a.e. bounded by some $c$ and $\|M_T\|_{\infty}$ is the greatest lower bound of the set of possible $c$'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just as a general related question, I am seeing in my text and online for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $||x||_\infty \le ||x||_1$, can we apply this here? For example: $||M_T||_\infty \le ||M_T||_1$?

Comment: If $X$ is bounded by $C$ (i.e. $|X|\leq C)$ then
$|\mathbb{E}[X]|\leq \mathbb{E}[|X|]=\|X\|_1\leq C$